# @PreAuthorize Spring Security - avoid duplicate queries to bdd

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an authorization class (Spring `@Component`) with methods that take an entity as a param and check whether the current user has the necessary rights to access it.

So first, I annotate my controller's method to check rights:

```java
@PreAuthorize("@authorizationComponent.hasPermission(@myService.findById(#entityId))")
```

This makes ***an initial query*** to the database to retrieve the entity via `findById`.

Then, once again, I want to retrieve the entity in the body of the method to perform my route logic:

```java
// can be inside a service method
MyEntity entity = this.myService.findById(entityId)
```

This makes ***a second request*** to the database.

**Is this the right way to do things with Spring?**
I know I could, for example, create a method in my authorization component that would return the loaded entity and which I could then call, but is this really the way to go?

I have complicated requirements for my authorizations, where I sometimes have to check that the entity is owned by a certain relationship to which the user have rights on it... This can quickly become complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using JPA , you can make sure `@Transactional` is executed before `@PreAuthorize` such that both business service method and the `@PreAuthorize` method are running in the same transaction as JPA will cache the entity that is fetched by Id into the 1st level cache for the same transaction.

That means in the `@PreAuthorize` method , it fetches the entity from DB and then will put it in the 1st level cache. Then later in the business method, it  will check if the 1st level cache contain the entity with the same Id. If yes it will get it without hitting DB.

You can configure the execution order of `@Transactional` and `@PreAuthorize`  through `@EnableTransactionManagement` and `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` like :

```java
@EnableTransactionManagement(order=1)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(order=2)
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {


}
```

Guess that the smaller order value will execute first but I leave it to you to confirm.

Comment: Thank you @Ken Chan it seems that `order` param is no longer available, since `@ EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` is deprecated.  And is it a "hack" or is it something common in large production applications?

Comment: Use `@EnableMethodSecurity` instead but not sure what is the replacement of the order  attribute. But it is still the same if you can make sure `@Transactional` to execute at the very beginning by setting it to have a very large priority.

Comment: what cause you think it is a hack ? i just use it very naturally based on the feature provided by spring and never use it in a strange way